# variable length for loop - tensorflow

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dynamic, tensorflow

I want to do for loop's with dynamic inputs in tensorflow.

I know for the code below `reduce_sum` is sufficient, but I want to be able to formulate code in the manner described below. So given that I have an array with different sizes, I want to traverse that array.

How can I traverse dynamic length arrays?

Problem:

> TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got Tensor

How can I evaluate get_sum that is outside the session?

`sum = get_sum(x, xshape)` shouldn't be in the `for` loop inside session

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])
xshape = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[])


def get_sum(x, xshape):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(xshape):
    sum += x[i]

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sum = get_sum(x, xshape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  for i in range(100):
    length = np.random.randint(0,10)
    a = np.random.randint(0, 10, length)
  print sess.run(sum,feed_dict={x:a, xshape:length})
```

Comment: If the number of iterations is unknown ahead of time, wouldn't another kind of loop be more appropriate?

Comment: what kind of loop?

Comment: Perhaps a `while` loop.

Comment: it is the same problem, you can't get shape as an integer; how are you going to use while loop?- the problem is to convert the shape into an integer, we need to evaluate it; the problem is how?

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with a loop, but rather how to get a certain integer: got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic loops are still young in TensorFlow, but they exist. Take a look for example at the fold operators and their implementation.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#foldl

Comment: What is the situation now? Thank you

Comment: Dynamic loops are well-supported now and there is a number of higher-level operators to make using them easier. You can do, e.g., `elems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ; sum = tf.foldl(lambda a, x: a + x, elems)`, check out tf.foldl and tf.scan API docs. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/foldl